# StackExchange link newtaber - Open links from questions and answers in new tab

Tags: script, hyperlinks

#### About

I needed to open links from posts and answers in the new tab instead of annoying in-place opening without `<Ctrl>` button or anything else just in ordinary way.

Because I did not find any sufficient solution of my problem I wrote own userscript which do what I want. If you have same issue you can install it from my repo:
[StackExchange link newtaber](https://github.com/almaceleste/userscripts/raw/master/src/StackExchange_link_newtaber.user.js)

This script should work in all StackExchange sites.

#### Download / Install

1. Install userscript extension for your browser from [Tampermonkey](https://tampermonkey.net/) website
2. Go to my [userscripts](https://github.com/almaceleste/userscripts) repository, open `StackExchange_link_newtaber.user.js` script and click `Raw` link - or simply click [here](https://github.com/almaceleste/userscripts/raw/master/src/StackExchange_link_newtaber.user.js)
3. Click `Install` in your browser extension window
4. Refresh opened pages
5. Enjoy

#### Platform

[image: Chrome]
[image: Firefox]
[image: Opera]
[image: Edge]
[image: Safari]
[image: Dolphin]
[image: UC]

#### Contact

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

#### License

[image: license]

#### Code

Tampermonkey userscript external libraries ([jQuery](https://jquery.com/), [GM_config](https://github.com/sizzlemctwizzle/GM_config/wiki))